# Prove that all set partitions are induced by equivalence relations.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Here is the question:

> Prove that if $P$ is a partition of a set $S$ then there exists an equivalence relation $R$ on $S$ such that $P = S/R$.

I'm very stuck with nowhere to go. Any Ideas?

Comment: Well, you can go with $x\equiv_P y\iff (\exists A\in P,\ x\in A\wedge y\in A)$.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help if you edit the question to show us what you know and where you are stuck. You can at least show us that you know and understand the definitions of "partition", "equivalence relation" and the $/$ construction. Or ask for help with some parts of those definitions.

Comment: Thank you!  Duly noted:)

Answer (score 0):

If $P$ is a partition of $S$ then $S$ is divided into disjoint sets say $$S_1, S_2, ...,S_k.$$

Define your equivalence relation $R$ on $S$ as the following:

$x$ is related to $y$ iff $x$ and $y$ are in the same $ S_i$ for some $i$, $1\le i\le k$

Note that the equivalency classes are exactly the partition sets   $S_i$ for $1\le i\le k$

Thus $P=S/R$